# I want to cache an entire list...but it won't fit in Memcache

Tags: memory, list, caching, memcached

Because this list is like 2MB big...and memcache max memory is only 1MB.

Is there a simple key/value alternative, just like memcache, except it can do bigger size?

Comment: 640k is all anyone will ever need on a PC... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're up for it, you can recompile memcached with a higher size limit, look here: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_items_limited_to_1_megabyte_in_size?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com). It is an open source clustering and highly scalable data distribution platform for Java. The current release is 1.8.4. The next one will have both Memcache and Rest interfaces available. You can give it a try.